# Why does my RegExp match in RegExr, but not in Python?

Tags: python, regex

```
regexp = re.compile('[A-Z]\\d{4}')
prefix = regexp.match("\"O1533_FOO\" INTEGER NOT NULL ,")
```

Prefix is None, but I expected it to be "O1533".

When I use the web based tool http://regexr.com/ it works.

http://regexr.com/3bag5

I tried to escape the `\` with different numbers of `\`s, and I also tried delimiting `/`s. Could not get it to work.

Can some RegExp expert please fix my expression?

Comment: Because `re.match` match the string form beginning . you need `re.search`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you should replace `match` with `search`.

`match` tries to match the string from the beginning, and `\"O1533_FOO\" INTEGER NOT NULL ,` doesn't begin with something that matches `[A-Z]`, hence it fails.

See [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a **match only at the beginning of the string**, while `re.search()` **checks for a match anywhere in the string** (this is what Perl does by default).